# Homework: DC circuit help

Tags: dc, circuit-analysis, theory, physics

I need help with the following problem:

Find range of resistance ***R4*** and voltage ***U4*** so that the range of current ***I*** is $$I \in [-3A,-1A]$$

[image]

***E=5V,
   E4=6V,
   Ig=1A,
   Ig4=-3A,
   R1=2ohm,
   R2=3ohm,
   R3=5ohm***

Firstly, I set current ***I=-3A***. Setting potential ***V3=0 V***, current ***I23=0.25 A***.

Using Kirchhoff's law on node 2 ***I12=1.25 A***. On node 1 ***I14=1.75 V***.

Now potential of nodes are ***V1=5 V, V2=1.25 V, V3=0 V V4=1.5 V***.

With potential of nodes method on node 4, ***R4=2.09 ohm***. Then, ***U4=-4.5 V***.

In my book's solution, it says that ***R4*** starts from ***0.22 ohm*** and ***U4*** starts from ***-4.5 V***.

Could someone check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the [superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem) to your circuit I have noticed that the current you are looking for can only be dependent from voltage source E, because when you are looking at another source, E is shorted, so your current gets 0A.  So now it depends on E alone (all other sources shorted or open).

- Ig is open
- Ig4 is open
- E4 is shorted

So R1 gets in serial to R4 and R2 and R3 get just serial, too. Finally the serial resistance groups are in parallel.

```
R14=2 Ω + R4
R23=8 Ω
=> R14|23 = (16 Ω + 8R4)/(10 Ω + R4)
I=-(E / R14|23)
 =-(50 Ω + 5R4)/(16 Ω + 8R4) A
=> R4=(-50 ΩA - 16I Ω )/(8I + 5 A)

When I=-3 A:
R4=2/19 Ω ≈ 0.1 Ω
When I=-1 A:
R4=34/3 Ω ≈ 11.3 Ω
```

As R4 is effectively rising with I, it must be that R4∈[0.1 Ω; 11.3 Ω].

Hope this helped a bit, though late....